# SCSS Contrast (from Compass) output different to LESS's contrast

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Trying to use the *.contrast-color* function in SCSS from the compass library is generating a different color to that of the *.contrast* which belongs in LESS even though the specification in LESS states otherwise.

> This function works the same way as the contrast function in Compass for SASS.
>   http://lesscss.org/functions/

Here is an example of me using the SCSS version of contrast-color and the outputted css.

[SCSS gist](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/487c40017dd30e99eda86be372a077bc)

and here is the LESS version.

[LESS version](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%2F*%5Cn%7C--------------------------------------------------------------------------%5Cn%7C%20jQuery%20Buttons%5Cn%7C--------------------------------------------------------------------------%5Cn*%2F%5Cn%5Cn.button-ui-state-hover(%40bg%2C%20%40border)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%26.ui-state-hover%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%2F%2F%20Hover%20is%20always%20slightly%20darker.%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctbackground-color%3A%20darken(%40bg%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctborder-color%3A%20darken(%40border%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctcolor%3A%20contrast(darken(%40bg%2C%2010%25))%3B%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.toolbar%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct.ui-button%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%40default-button-color%3A%20%239f9f9f%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%26.ui-state-default%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40bg%3A%20%40default-button-color%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40border%3A%20darken(%40bg%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40color%3A%20contrast(%40bg)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctborder-color%3A%20%40border%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctbackground-color%3A%20%40bg%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctfont-weight%3A%20normal%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctcolor%3A%20%40color%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct.button-ui-state-hover(%40bg%2C%20%40border)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%2F%2F%20Make%20the%20refresh%20button%20bright%20green.%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%26.intention__grid-refresh.refresh-required%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40bg%3A%20%2332cd32%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40border%3A%20%232bb22b%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40-webkit-keyframes%20toolbar-button-refresh-pulse%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct50%25%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctbackground-color%3A%20lighten(%40bg%2C%2010%25)%20!important%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40keyframes%20toolbar-button-refresh-pulse%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct50%25%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctbackground-color%3A%20lighten(%40bg%2C%2010%25)%20!important%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%26.ui-state-default%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctbackground%3A%20%40bg%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctcolor%3A%20%23fff%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctborder-color%3A%20%40border%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct-webkit-animation-duration%3A%201s%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctanimation-duration%3A%201s%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct-webkit-animation-fill-mode%3A%20both%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctanimation-fill-mode%3A%20both%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct-webkit-animation-iteration-count%3A%20infinite%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctanimation-iteration-count%3A%20infinite%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct-webkit-animation-name%3A%20toolbar-button-refresh-pulse%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctanimation-name%3A%20toolbar-button-refresh-pulse%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct.button-ui-state-hover(%40bg%2C%20%40border)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%26.ui-button-toggle%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctwidth%3A%204em%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctpadding%3A%200%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Cttext-align%3A%20left%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct.ui-button-icon-primary%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctwidth%3A%20100%25%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctmargin-left%3A%20-20px%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%26.fa%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctmargin-left%3A%206px%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%26.ui-button-toggle-on%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40bg%3A%20average(%40default-button-color%2C%20%235cb85c)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40border%3A%20darken(%40bg%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%26.ui-state-default%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctbackground%3A%20%40bg%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctcolor%3A%20contrast(%40bg)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctborder-color%3A%20%40border%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct.button-ui-state-hover(%40bg%2C%20%40border)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct.ui-button-icon-primary.fa%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctcontent%3A%20%5C%22%5C%5Cf205%5C%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20The%20FontAwesome%20%5C%22toggle-on%5C%22%20icon.%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%26.ui-button-toggle-off%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40bg%3A%20average(%40default-button-color%2C%20%23d9534f)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%40border%3A%20darken(%40bg%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%26.ui-state-default%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctbackground%3A%20%40bg%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctcolor%3A%20contrast(%40bg)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctborder-color%3A%20%40border%3B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct.button-ui-state-hover(%40bg%2C%20%40border)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct.ui-button-icon-primary.fa%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctcontent%3A%20%5C%22%5C%5Cf204%5C%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20The%20FontAwesome%20%5C%22toggle-off%5C%22%20icon.%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

Is there a like for like LESS contrast function in SCSS? If not, how would one go about converting it. Looking at the source there seems to be a fair few dependenices within LESS for the contrast to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reason:**

No, the two functions are not the same. In Less, the `contrast` function compares the colors based on the gamma corrected luma value. Below is the extract from the [Less documentation](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast):

> In accordance with WCAG 2.0, colors are compared using their gamma-corrected luma value, not their lightness.

Whereas in Sass, they are [comparing the colors based on `brightness` of the colors](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/color/contrast/#function-contrast-color). This function is giving the [luminance value as the output](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/color/brightness/) and not the luma value. So they are giving different outputs.

---

**Solution:**

While Less has a [`luma` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-channel-luma) to directly get the gamma corrected luma value also, Sass doesn't seem to have any built-in functions to provide this value. So, we have to write custom functions  based on the [WCAG 2.0 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#relativeluminancedef). The calculation logic is provided there and below is the extract:

> For the sRGB colorspace, the relative luminance of a color is defined as L = 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B where R, G and B are defined as:
>
> if RsRGB <= 0.03928 then R = RsRGB/12.92 else R = ((RsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
>
> if GsRGB <= 0.03928 then G = GsRGB/12.92 else G = ((GsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
>
> if BsRGB <= 0.03928 then B = BsRGB/12.92 else B = ((BsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
>   and RsRGB, GsRGB, and BsRGB are defined as:
>
> RsRGB = R8bit/255
>
> GsRGB = G8bit/255
>
> BsRGB = B8bit/255

I'm not a Sass expert to write this custom function by myself, so I took some help from [this article by Toni Pinel](https://medium.com/@tonipinel/how-to-get-an-accurate-contrast-color-with-sass-b0ebc01bf17f#.jrfrion7k) (well, almost everything bar his `re-gamma` function). If you use the below `contrast-color` function, it would provide the same output as Less.

```css
@function de-gamma($n) { @if $n <= 0.03928 { @return $n / 12.92; } @else { @return pow((($n + 0.055)/1.055),2.4); } }

// sRGB BT-709 BRIGHTNESS
@function brightness($c) {
    $rlin: de-gamma(red($c)/255);
    $glin: de-gamma(green($c)/255);
    $blin: de-gamma(blue($c)/255);
    @return (0.2126 * $rlin + 0.7152 * $glin + 0.0722 * $blin) * 100;
}

// Compares contrast of a given color to the light/dark arguments and returns whichever is most "contrasty"
@function contrast-color($color, $dark: #000000, $light: #FFFFFF) {
    @if $color == null {
        @return null;
    }

    @else {
        $color-brightness: brightness($color);
        $light-text-brightness: brightness($light);
        $dark-text-brightness: brightness($dark);

        @return if(abs($color-brightness - $light-text-brightness) > abs($color-brightness - $dark-text-brightness), $light, $dark);
    }
}
```

---

Below is the code that [Less is using for the `luma` function](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/24523c6a869a2337a6ca3e9e10eb1a06eeca5fa7/lib/less/tree/color.js) and it is very similar to the custom function given above. This function returns the same output as the Sass custom function given above.

```
Color.prototype.luma = function () {
    var r = this.rgb[0] / 255,
        g = this.rgb[1] / 255,
        b = this.rgb[2] / 255;

    r = (r <= 0.03928) ? r / 12.92 : Math.pow(((r + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4);
    g = (g <= 0.03928) ? g / 12.92 : Math.pow(((g + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4);
    b = (b <= 0.03928) ? b / 12.92 : Math.pow(((b + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4);

    return 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b;
};
```

**Notes:**

1. If we use `luma(darken(@bg,10%))`, Less compiler is giving 23.64695145 as the output. This is slightly different from the Sass custom function's output, which is 23.83975738. But `luma(#868686)` gives the same output as the Sass custom function and so I don't think the custom function is wrong.
2. Some SASS compilers do not have the native `pow()` function which is required by the `de-gamma` function used above. For this reason, you may need to include a library which has this or at least the `pow()` function from such a library. An example would be Sassy-Math.

Comment: Voted. Will try this out once I can. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Euphoria: You're welcome. Please take your time to test it out. I did a random check for your color and the luma value that I'm getting from this Sass custom function is 23.83975738 whereas the output Less' luma function is 23.64695145. It is still not an exact match but it should work for 99% cases. We'd have to look at the Less source code if we want a more closer match because this Sass custom function is inline with WCAG 2.0 spec.

Comment: Okay, here's the result. Perfect function and thank you for such a well written explanation, it is highly appreciated. There was however one issue (no fault of yours) which was that certain scss compilers do not have the "pow" function which is being used in de-gamma. For that you must use a SCSS extension library or at least the pow() SCSS function. We went with @import "sassy-math"; and in our project took over just the POW function to include in the scss for now (might add sassy-math later if need be). This may be worth noting in the answer. Again, thank you.

Comment: @Euphoria: Ah, I thought `pow` must be a Sass function. Let me see if there is any alternate for that without using an extra library. Will update the answer if I find one :)

Comment: I've added the note for you should you wish to edit/keep it etc. :)

Comment: @Harry, does sass-math works correctly ? I have included from " https://raw.githubusercontent.com/at-import/Sassy-math/master/sass/math.scss" and getting error "Error: 2.4 is not an integer."